# How to remove Gantry 5 and theme

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, gantry

I installed Gantry 5 and the Hydrogen theme just to see what it's all about and I'd like to remove it.

It was not specified that just playing around with the theme to see how it works would cause it to become the default and hijack the current template. I managed to get my template back as the current, but can't seem to remove the Hydrogen theme or the Gantry components.

Could someone guide me on removing this ?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess now that you should have realized that it's not wise to just play around anywhere. Kids in the city would play in the playground and not in the avenue. When you want to play or experiment with extensions and Joomla, you don't do it on a production site, rather on site where disaster would have no impact. Make this your golden rule.

Answer (score 3):

To completely uninstalling Gantry (including its plugins, files, libs module) you need to uninstall the Gantry 5 **[Package](https://docs.joomla.org/Package)**.

From your joomla administrator page go to : *Extensions > Manage > Manage* then in the sidebar, change the filter type dropdown to **Package**.
Go to the right side then search for 'Gantry'. You should see Gantry 5 Package in the list, simply check the checkbox and click the uninstall button. All Gantry related extensions (plugins, libs, modules etc) should have been removed now

To uninstall the hydrogen template, simply repeat above steps, but when choosing the type filter, choose **Template**

Hydrogen also creates a new menu when you install it. It also creates a new menu item and set it as a default menu item. To fix this, go to your Menu>Main menu, set Home as the default menu. Then go to Menu>Manage then delete the Hydrogen menu

Comment: I tried that.

The Hydrogen theme still exists. It also has the 'home' icon in the 'Menus' dropdown.

With the Gantry package uninstalled I get component not found errors.  

With it installed, the featured articles do not display.

Comment: Try to purge your joomla cache, select Site → Maintenance → Clear Cache from the drop-down menus.

Comment: Tried that, too.  What I see is the Hydrogen theme is still installed and is set as the default theme (it has the 'Home' icon beside it in the Menus dropdown).  I can't delete the theme as long as this is the case, and I'm having difficulty locating how to set my theme as the default.  I'm also getting COM_GANTRY5_PARTICLE_NOT_INITIALIZED where the featured articles should be displayed.

Comment: 1. Set the template to something else
2. Use phpmyadmin to delete the theme "xxx_template_styles"
3. COM_GANTRY problem - is probably a GANTRY module

Comment: You can't uninstall the default template. Set your default template to protostar first then uninstall the hydrogen template by following the steps I described above. If needed, you can reinstall the template and gantry package again before uninstalling it.

Comment: I think I know the problem. Hydrogen also creating a new menu when you install it. It also creates a new menu item and set it as a default menu item. To fix this, go to your Menu>Main menu, set Home as the default menu. Then go to Menu>Manage then delete the Hydrogen menu